# Open Graph, Custom Story

Tags: facebook-opengraph, feed

we created a custom open graph story with a map attachment. We're using the new object api for this flow if this is important. What now seems not to work is that the custom actions only appear at the activity protocol of the user but not on the news feed.

What we got:
1 custom object wich inherits from Object
1 custom action with a refernce to our custom object

Map attachment looks good on the app edit page too. It appears as stated above on the timeline too but the news feed is empty.

Anyone faced something same before?

Comment: Facebook selects and filters what to show in the news feed. Go down the news feed maybe you will find it there. If it doesn't help try to change the sorting of the news feed. Change it to `Most Recent`.

Comment: Thanks Yervand. So the conclusion is: If it shows on the activity protocol we made everything - technically - correct?

Comment: We are talking about posting an action yes?

Comment: Yes. A custom open graph story. In my case: A story with an map attachment

Comment: Yes it is approved. It only doesn't show up on the newsfeed.

Comment: In that case the only problem is what I told in the first comment. If you want to be sure ask your friends to like the post on your timeline as soon as you post a new action. It will increase the chances your other friends will see it on their news feed(for testing reasons)

Comment: Thanks Yervand. I just wanted to make sure that our implementation is technically ok. Could you make an answer on this which I could accept?

Comment: @onigunn is the map attachment still working for you. Can't for the life of me get it displaying as a map. I've done it before too which makes me think something has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook selects and filters what to show in the news feed. Go down the news feed maybe you will find it there. If it doesn't help try to change the sorting of the news feed. Change it to Most Recent.